# Using SQL joins to determine order of a post

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to fetch forum topics based on the amount of replies that has been submitted for a topic. I am somewhat new to understanding how SQL joins work, though I have been using SQL for awhile in general, though I feel like I am on the right track. I currently have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `topics`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(tid) as countedReplies,`tid`
    FROM `replies`
    GROUP BY `tid`
)
ON topics.id = replies.tid
ORDER by replies.countedReplies DESC
```

Table structures look something like this:

**topics**

```
ID        Topic Name
1         Filler Topic Name
2         Exciting Posts about Excellence
3         Random name for example
```

**replies**

```
ID       tid       Post
1        3         Hooray! Wonderful!
2        3         I am a post to topic id 3 as well!
3        1         Topic 1 is better than topic 1.
```

---

**My expected result**

I am getting nothing in return, though I am trying to get something like this:

```
1. Random name for example
2. Filler Topic Name
3. Exciting Posts about Excellence
```

Comment: What problem are you having? You won't get any entry for topic 2 because there are no replies to it, so there won't be any rows for it in the subquery. Use a `LEFT JOIN` to include topics with no matches in the subquery.

Comment: @Barmar with what I supplied, I do not get any results.

Comment: You should actually be getting an error, since you didn't assign an alias to the subquery.

Comment: That is actually one of my issues I seem to have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join without involving any sub select

```
SELECT t.* FROM `topics` t
LEFT JOIN `replies` r
ON t.id = r.tid
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER by count(r.tid) DESC
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5cf4/2)

Comment: That works exactly how I wanted it to, thank you very much. I will accept the answer when it lets me.